# why do i get a compilation error when i add a click event to a button in a page linked to a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting this error every time I add a button in my page:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

and

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'addproduct_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnadd_Click' and no extension method 'btnadd_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'addproduct_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 166:            <div class="row">
Line 167:                <div class="col-md-3">
Line 168:                    <asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="Save details" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnadd_Click" />
Line 169:                </div>
Line 170:                <div class="col-md-7"></div>
```

When i delete the OnClick="btnadd_Click" the the compilation error does not appear so i seems the error occurs each time i add the onclick line. The page is linked to a masterpage as shown..

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/adminmaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="addproduct.aspx.cs" Inherits="onlineshop.addproduct" %>
```

Even when I try and delete and add a new button I still get the compilation error please help?

Comment: whats in your designer?

Comment: Do you have `btnadd_Click` method in the code behind?

Comment: yap i have it looks like this:
protected void add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: @simon what do you mean?

Comment: in WebForms projects you have your aspx, aspx.cs \ aspx.vb and then you have your aspx.cs.designer. Whats in this file relating to the button that you have added. Also, have you tried a Clean and a Rebuild?

Comment: What do you mean by clean and how do i do it?

Comment: The error message says `does not contain a definition for 'btnadd_Click'`. You mentioned above you named the handler `protected void add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. The runtime is expecting to find a function called `btnadd_Click` not `add_button_Click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create the method in CS file of this name **btnadd_Click**  With Parameters Manually

```
void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //snip
    }
```